# nginx can't create virtual host on port 8080

Tags: nginx

Am running `nginx version: nginx/1.19.2 (Ubuntu)` ,

I've set a virtual host for my domain on port 8080 , below is how the virtual host looks like

```
    server {
        listen       8080;
        #listen       example.com:8080;
        server_name  example.com  www.example.com  *.example.com;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/example.com;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
```

i've defined the virtual host inside the main nginx configuration file i.e. `nginx.conf`

When i try to access example.com:8080 , the page returns 522 timeout status

8080 is allowed in firewall, i've tried almost everything, i even built nginx from source but still no luck.

When i tail error logs after the page times out, nothing gets logged. N.B i compiled nginx with the `--with-debug` flag to enable logging of almost everything, but still nothing shows up on the logs.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Check your CloudFlare DNS settings.

Comment: i removed cloudflare, my domain points directly to my server via A records, still not getting port 8080 to work, i even tried port 8000. Same thing, the page times out without any response